# Using variables inside an if statement in python

Tags: python

How do I use a variable inside an if statement in python? For example, `month_report` contains:

```
October
November
December
January
```

and `cycle_report` contains:

```
October,Monthly
November,Monthly
November,Quarterly
January,Monthly
```

Below is how I would think variable can be used.

```
mcount = 0
qcount = 0
ncount = 0

for month in month_report:
    for x in cycle_report:
        if x == "{month},Monthly":
            mcount += 1
        elif x == "{month},Quarterly":
            qcount += 1
        else:
            ncount += 1
```

Comment: Is `cycle_report` map? If so, then it would be `cycle_report[month]`, as value would be report. If full `"{month},Monthly"` is key, then you would have to format it before checking.

Comment: `f"{month},Monthly"` ?

Comment: Sorry I am fairly new in python. How do I exactly use that? ```f"{month},Monthly"```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your data structure, but considering they are list of strings:

```
In [1]: month_report = ['October', 'November']

In [2]: cycle_report = ['October, monthly', 'November, monthly']

In [3]: for month in month_report:
   ...:     for cycle in cycle_report:
   ...:         if month + ', monthly' == cycle:
   ...:             print('yes')
   ...:
yes
yes
```